# Converting use of memcpy to std::copy

Tags: c++, stl

I have a bit of code that that uses memcpy and I am trying to convert it over to using std::copy. I am getting stuck on the syntax but this is code currently works for memcpy

```
length=sizeof(int)+title.size()*80;
char *otitle=new char [length];
unsigned int *ntitle=reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(otitle);
*ntitle=title.size();
for (i=0; i< title.size(); i++){
  memcpy(otitle+sizeof(int)+i*80, getTitle(i).c_str(), 80);
  //std::copy(getTitle(i).begin(), getTitle(i).end() , otitle);
}

doSomething(otitle, length);
delete otitle;
```

The line that is commented out isn't correct and so I would appreciate any help. Essentially, "title" is an std::vector and the function "getTitle()" returns the string in the ith element of "title. otitle is a long character array and I want to be able to copy over each element of "title" into otitle (see memcpy).

Comment: Does `getTitle` return the string by reference, or by value?

Comment: Why do you calculate `length` using `sizeof(int) + title.size()*80`? What does `length` represent? Why the `reinterpret_cast` with `<unsigned int*>`? What exactly do you want in `otitle`? The concatenation of all the strings in the `title` vector? Might something as simple as using `std::string` and its `operator+=` for concatenation be just fine?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: getTitle returns the string by value.

Comment: @Mr.C64: otitle should point to a character array where the title is concatenated from getTitle(). The function "doSomething" takes a char* as the first argument and isn't something that I can change. As posed in the title, the question is about how to use std::copy instead of memcpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `getTitle` returns a string by value, when you call it twice, you get two different strings. You need to make sure you are calling `begin` and `end` on the same string though. So you can store the result in another string variable.

```
std::string str = getTitle(i);
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), otitle + sizeof(int) + i*80);
```

If your original version with memcpy handles copying over a null-terminator (can't tell from your snippet), you'll need to handle that manually. There are other details that might be wrong here, because I don't know the exact details of what your code is supposed to be doing, but this at least gives a correct usage of `std::copy`.

Comment: Your answer seems to have worked. I actually tried something similar but without using an intermediate "std::string str" (i.e. std::copy(getTitle(i).begin(), getTitle(i).end(), otitle+sizeof(int)+i*80).  However, I still don't quite understand the logic when you say, "when you call it twice, you get two different strings". It would be great if you could help me see the difference.

Comment: @slaw: Since the function returns by value, it creates a copy of the string that was returned. So the first time you call it, it creates a copy, which is distinct from the original. The second time you call it, it creates *another* copy, which is distinct both from the original, and from the first copy.

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand. Since getTitle returns a string by value then that means that I am getting two separate copies of the string. So the begin() and end() would not be corresponding to the same string. Is that correct?